# create ref curser with parameters?

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

how can I create ref curser with parameters and return this cursor from plsql function?
I tried to write something like this code..

```
create or replace function get_ref_cur(id in number) return sys_refcursor is
 ref_curs sys_refcursor; 
 begin 
    open ref_curs(std_id number) for select * from student where id = std_id;
 return ref_curs; 
 end;
```

but this code did not work.

Comment: one `?` per question is enough. And "did not work" is not a good problem description, please specify what it does/doesn't do (fails to compile?, returns wrong data?, ...)

Comment: What is "ID" and "STD_ID" ? If ID is a table column, you don't want it as the name of the function parameter. If STD_ID is the table column, what is the "(std_id number)" trying to do ?

Comment: id is a table column and std_id is the cursor parameter the problem in the parameters of the cursor when I write open ref_curs(std_id number) the compiler give an syntax error.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't need to apply parameters to a plain sys_refcursor.

```
create or replace function get_ref_cur(id in number) return sys_refcursor is
 ref_curs sys_refcursor; 
 begin 
    open ref_curs for select * from student where std_id = id;
 return ref_curs; 
 end;
```